# Core Data unique constraints - "Dangling reference to an invalid object" on save

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm introducing Unique Constraints to an existing app, in a new model version.

The model has entity Person which has an optional one-to-one relationship with entity Pet. Person's delete rule is cascade, and Pet's inverse relationship delete rule is nullify. There's another entity, Job, which Person also has a to-one relationship. But that deletion rule, and the inverse deletion rule, are both nullify.

Person has a "personID" property which I've made unique.

In a main queue context I've got an instance of Person, with ID xxx, that has no Pet set. Let's call that person "Charlie". I create a Job as well, and set that as "iOS Dev", and assign it to Charlie's job property.

Then in a child private queue context, I insert a new "Charlie" also with ID xxx (the unique constraint) and create a Pet and set it. I don't set a Job. I save the child context with no issue.

Immediately after, I attempt to save the Main Queue context. But just before that, I inspect the insertedObjects property of the Main Queue context and see, as I expect to, an instance of Person with ID xxx. What I'm expecting is that this second instance will be handled by unique constraints and be "merged" with the original instance of Person from the prior paragraph. But, when I actually call the MOC's save: method, it throws an exception and I inspect the NSError object:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)" UserInfo={Dangling reference to an
>   invalid object.=null

Any ideas on how to avoid the exception? I'm used to "Dangling references" in Core Data meaning a relationship is misconfigured, but I've gone over it a number of times and it looks fine, so I'm not sure what else to troubleshoot. I have all contexts involved using the NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy merge policy.

Obviously this is a little hard to follow, so I threw a sample project up on Github in case anybody is interested: https://github.com/bpapa/core-data-unique-bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wound up burning a Code-Level Support ticket on this, and an Apple engineer confirmed that there is a bug. As a workaround, it was recommended to write my own merge policy that calls super and then manually makes sure the relationship is set on both ends.

Comment: In my case, upgrading to Xcode 8.2 made the issue disappear!

Comment: That's good to hear. In my app, I found writing my own merge policy didn't fix it, so I actually wound up just moving away from relying on the Unique feature, which means a lot of extra create-or-update code and also needing to queue up my operations that save to core data. Hopefully at some point I can revisit this.

Comment: I have to retract my joyful comment from October 29th – this issue has come back with a vengeance and I now believe that the 1550 dangling reference error only appeared to disappear because I had reset the content on the simulator. In my case, I get 1550 when my content refreshes from the server and my app attempts to update existing objects in Core Data.

I am now using release version 8.2 and still attempting to solve my issue, assuming it's still not due to a bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to employ the new iOS 9 Unique Constrains strategy, you have to make sure that **both contexts have the same merge policy** set.

Note that this will **not** help you if you have a scenario where the newer instance of the object has an attribute/relationship that is `nil` and your intention is to always "augment" the object, i.e. fill any missing attributes and update existing ones.

Otherwise, for pre-iOS9, the following is valid.

Perhaps there is some misunderstanding about the meaning of the merge policy you employ (`NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`). It refers to a situation where you have one version of an object in memory and another in the persistent store, not two versions in memory in different contexts. From the header files:

> This singleton policy merges conflicts between the persistent store's version of the object and the current in memory version.

Thus, your process of creating **new** object is not the correct approach.

Instead, you should fetch the `Person` in the child context using the unique ID.

Alternatively, you could make the person's `objectID` (an opaque Core Data artifact) available to the child context to get a reference to the same object in the object graph using `objectWithID:`.

Comment: But I thought the whole purpose of Unique Constraints in iOS 9 is that i don't have to a "fetch or create" type of thing? I'm doing this to avoid duplicates of records that may be created in another thread, which I believe was one of the problems Unique Constraints was supposed to help solve.

Comment: OK - I see where you are coming from. You need to set the merge policy on *both contexts*, otherwise it will not work. I still prefer working on the same managed object rather than relying on a rather opaque merging strategy (because it is more explicit and debuggable), but your approach should work as well.

Comment: It should! I am setting the merge policy on all contexts involved here. I'm pretty sure this is an Apple bug at this point but will be investigating.

Comment: I think you should go with my recommendation. The is a lazy hack, if you ask me, and it is by far preferable to explicitly update-or-create.

Comment: Also, I think I found the reason why your setup is not working. Please review the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with your second paragraph. In my sample project, if I comment out line 59 in the view controller (to avoid the Exception being thrown), and then launch, tap the button, and then quit the app and view the underlying SQLite database, the Person's "job" column is still set despite the fact that the property was nil when saving the 2nd Person.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the changes into the main context using the did save notification from the background context. See Apples Earthquakes sample.